# I have a problem with an console error setting innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i have this error:

```
quiz.js:121 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')
    at pytanie (quiz.js:121:28)
    at czas (quiz.js:24:5)
    at onload (quiz2.html:9:23)
```

I tried solve it for 3 days but still i don't know what is a problem. I will be very glad if you can help me!

code:

```
function czas()
{
    var i = 59;
    var min = 5;
    window.myinterval = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('czas').innerHTML = "Pozostały czas: " + min + ": " + i;

        if(i == 0 && min == 0)
        {
            clearInterval(myinterval);
            getwyniki();
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
            if(i == 0 && min > 0)
            {
                i = 1;
                min--;
            }
        }
    }, 3000);
    pytanie();
}

function getwyniki() {
    clearInterval(myinterval);
    var amountCorrect = 0;
    
    for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var radiosname = document.getElementsByName('pytanie' + i);
    for(var j = 0; j < radiosname.length; j++)
    {
        var radiosvalue = radiosname[j];
        if(radiosvalue.checked){
            if(radiosvalue.value == 't')
            {
            amountCorrect++;
            radiosvalue.nextSibling.style.color = "green";
        }
        else
        {
            radiosvalue.nextSibling.style.color = "red";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        radiosvalue.nextSibling.style.color = "";
    }
}
}
if(amountCorrect <= 10 && amountCorrect >= 8)
{
    document.getElementById('ocena').innerHTML = ("Twoja ocena to: " + 5);
}
if(amountCorrect == 7)
{
    document.getElementById('ocena').innerHTML = ("Twoja ocena to: " + 4);
}
if(amountCorrect == 6)
{
    document.getElementById('ocena').innerHTML = ("Twoja ocena to: " + 3);
}
if(amountCorrect == 5)
{
    document.getElementById('ocena').innerHTML = ("Twoja ocena to: " + 2);
}
if(amountCorrect < 5)
{
    document.getElementById('ocena').innerHTML = ("Twoja ocena to: " + 1);
}
document.getElementById('wyniki').innerHTML = "Poprawnie udzielone odpowiedzi: " + amountCorrect + "<br>" + "<h3>dobrze odpowiedzi były to:<br> 1.a <br> 2.c<br> 3.d<br> 4.a</h3>";
}


function pytanie()
{
    var pytanie = ["pytanie 1", "pytanie 2", "pytanie 3", "pytanie 4", "pytanie 5", "pytanie 6", "pytanie 7", "pytanie 8", "pytanie 9", "pytanie 10",];
    var ask = pytanie.slice();
    var tmpArray =[0];
    var pname = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
    //document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = "sda";
    //console.log('i :' +i);
    var tmp = i+1;
    if (tmp < 5)
    {
    pname[i] = document.getElementById('p' + tmp);
    console.log(pname[i]);
    }
    if (i == 0)
    {
        tmpArray[0] = Math.floor(Math.random() * ask.length);
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            var flag = false;
            var liczba = Math.floor(Math.random() * ask.length);
            for(var j = 0; j < tmpArray.length;j++)
            {
                console.log("liczba: " + liczba + "ar: " + tmpArray[j]);
                if (liczba == tmpArray[j])
                    flag = true;
            }

        }while(flag == true);

        tmpArray.push(liczba);

    }
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < pytanie.length; j++)
    {
        console.log('tmp: ' + tmpArray[j]);
        //console.clear();
        pname[j].innerHTML = pytanie[tmpArray[j]];
        console.log('pname: ' + pname[j]);
    }
}
```

html:

```
<p id="p1"></p>
    <input type="radio" name="pytanie1" value="t"><span>a)</span>
    <input type="radio" name="pytanie1" value="f"><span>b)</span>
    <input type="radio" name="pytanie1" value="f"><span>c)</span>
    <input type="radio" name="pytanie1" value="f"><span>d)</span>
    <h3>Pytanie 2</h3>
```

and same 3 more blocks with id's + 1. ^
id's: p1, p2, p3, p4. This error doesn't do anything for my quiz but i want my quiz clear without errors.
I tried change id's, delete table and make new but it doesn't do anything. But i saw that when I delete [j] from "pname[j].innerHTML = pytanie[j];" then the error disappear, but if i delete [j] it will assign same question to that id's. I want to assign random question to id's p1 p2 p3 p4 and I tried anything what i know and what i find in internet.

Comment: It seems your question is not related to java?

Comment: oh, Yes it's related to js only so sorry i will delete it

Comment: As the error hints: the element where you want to set the HTML is undefined (e.g. because an element with the ID you are searching for doesn't exist). So either you have to ensure, that the DOM object, where you want to manipulate the HTML, exists or you have to check wether the object could be found and only set the HTML when this conditions is fullfilled.

Comment: `<p id="p4"></p>``<p id="p3"></p>``<p id="p2"></p>``<p id="p1"></p>`
So my my element exist and to be honest i don't know how to set this to full filled because i learn js for couple months. I haveto write 'text' and then this will be removed by innerHTML or what i have to set this to filled?

Comment: i've added html if it will help @Fatorice

Comment: Because the error is about `undefined` and not `null` I'm pretty sure it is related to this line: `pname[j].innerHTML = pytanie[tmpArray[j]];`. And if I interpret your code correctly `pname` has only `6` elements and `pytanie` has more than `6` elements. And it likely has to be `for(var j = 0; j < pname.length; j++)` instead of `for(var j = 0; j < pytanie.length; j++)`

Comment: @Fatorice functions that search for one element in the dom like `getElementById()` return `null` if the element was not found not `undefined`. Having `undefined` indicates more an out-of-bounds access to an array, or access to a property that does not exists.

Comment: @t.niese Oh, thanks! now it work great without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response in the comment the problem was `pname[j].innerHTML = pytanie[tmpArray[j]];`.

And more precisely the loop `for(var j = 0; j < pytanie.length; j++)` where `pytanie.length` was used instead of  `pname.length`.

Because `pytanie` has more elements then `pname` this resulted in an out-of-bounds access at `pname[j].innerHTML` with the result that `pname[j].` evaluates to `undefined`.